# Filebeat | how to define a unique index for different log paths?

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, log-shipping

I am collecting logs from two different paths:

- /var/log/containers/*.log
- /var/log/agents/*.log

I wanted a that files from each of the paths will be sent to different indexes in elasticsearch.
I tried to define the filebeat configuration as follow:

```
    output.elasticsearch:
    protocol: http
    hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    compression_level: 1
    indices:
    - index: "agent-logs"
      when:
       contains:
        log.file.path: "/var/log/agents/*.log"
    - index: "container-logs"
      when:
       contains:
        log.file.path: "/var/log/containers/*.log"
```

I also tried:

```
    output.elasticsearch:
    protocol: http
    hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    compression_level: 1
    indices:
    - index: "agent-logs"
      when.contains:
        log.file.path: "/var/log/agents/*.log"
    - index: "container-logs"
      when.contains:
        log.file.path: "/var/log/containers/*.log"
```

and:

```
    output.elasticsearch:
    protocol: http
    hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    compression_level: 1
    indices:
    - index: "agent-logs"
      when.equals:
        log.file.path: "/var/log/agents/*.log"
    - index: "container-logs"
      when.equals:
        log.file.path: "/var/log/containers/*.log"
```

But nothing seems to be working.
Please help!

thank you

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR;

`equals` and `contains` do not support glob patterns.
You may want to look into `regexp` instead ? or another distinct value.

## Solution

This might work better:

```yaml
output.elasticsearch:
    protocol: http
    hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    compression_level: 1
    indices:
    - index: "agent-logs"
      when:
       contains:
        log.file.path: "agents"
    - index: "container-logs"
      when:
       contains:
        log.file.path: "containers"
```

Comment: Thank you @paulo, I have another issue... logs from /var/log/agents/*.log are not even passing to elasticsearch although they exist in the path, you know what might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your answer!
But I have another issue... logs from /var/log/agents/*.log are not even passing to elasticsearch although they exist in the path, you know what might be the reason?

this is the full config file:

```
   filebeat.autodiscover:
     providers:
      - type: kubernetes
        hints.enabled: true
        hints.default_config:
          enabled: false
          type: container
          paths:
            - /var/log/containers/*.log  # CRI path
            - /var/log/agents/*.log

  output.elasticsearch:
    protocol: http
    hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    compression_level: 1
    indices:
    - index: "agent-logs"
      when:
       contains:
        log.file.path: "agents"
    - index: "container-logs"
      when:
       contains:
        log.file.path: "containers"
```

and I also tried this config, but when I run this config I only get agent logs:

```
  filebeat.autodiscover:
    providers:
      - type: kubernetes
        hints.enabled: true
        hints.default_config:
          enabled: false
          type: container
          paths:
            - /var/log/containers/*.log
  filebeat.inputs:
   - type: filestream
     id: agent-filestream
     paths:
      - "/var/log/agents/*.log"

  output.elasticsearch:
    protocol: http
    hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    compression_level: 1
    indices:
    - index: "container-logs"
      when:
       contains:
        log.file.path: "containers"
    - index: "agent-logs"
      when:
       contains:
        log.file.path: "agents"
```

what do you think?

Comment: You should open another question.